# Does Ubuntu One support Content-Range?

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-one-api

Using Ubuntu One's Cloud API, I try to download only the first 144 bytes of a file, using the [`Range: bytes=0-143`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35.2) directive in the HTTP header of my request.

As a response, I receive the following HTTP header (along with the status code 206, aka "Partial content"):

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=blah.txt
Date: Mon, 21 Jan 2013 23:30:06 GMT
X-Bzr-Revision-Number: 6696
Etag: "sha1:7f96fcfa002cf5791c976c46aaf733dc523d9041;gzip"
Content-Range: bytes 0-143/3909
Via: 1.0 calamansi.canonical.com:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE7) 1.1 files.one.ubuntu.com
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
X-Cache: MISS from calamansi.canonical.com
Set-Cookie: sessionid=...; Domain=.one.ubuntu.com; httponly; Path=/; secure
Server: TwistedWeb/10.0.0
Last-Modified: Mon, 21 Jan 2013 23:17:05 GMT
```

So apparently, according to the header I receive, I am being given 144 bytes, those which I requested. However, the body is empty. Note also that [`Content-Length`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.16) is not present in the header of the response...

Is the response header from Ubuntu One deceiving me, and the server doesn't really support the `Range` directive?

Comment: Since this is a bug, it probably be closed as off-topic, in accordance with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/22949).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug was opened at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/1103136 to track this. Will be following up there.